# Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia, torch

I am trying to GPU accelerate some code and am checking if my editor recognizes that I have a GPU (note my editor is VScode and this is all on a windows system). I run the following code:

```py
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

And get the following error:
`AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling torch and CUDA to no avail. I have CUDA 12.1 and torch 2.0.1.When I run nvidia-smi in the command prompt, I get the following output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 531.14                 Driver Version: 531.14       CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                      TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 L...  WDDM | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P0               22W /  N/A|      0MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm not really sure why this isn't working and I haven't found any posts that clearly explain why. I am not sure if this is an issue with dependencies and if so how to change the version of CUDA.

I have tried changing CUDA versions by purging my current installation and downloading a new toolkit; however, my whenever I run nvcc--version or nvidia-smi it says I have CUDA 12.1 and not the new version I downloaded.

Comment: Did you install the CUDA version of Torch? On windows the CPU version is the default Torch package.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Are you using conda?